# How to set dimensions of an element to fill only the initial window/viewport size?

Tags: html, css, viewport

I'm trying to make an element maintain only to the initial 100% height of the viewport. So anytime the user resize their windows, the height shouldn't be responsive.

Am i suppose to write javascript to get the initial viewport height and then create those deliver those dimensions to the css? Anybody can show me how to do that?

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.top {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: yellow;
}


.bottom {
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}
```

class top is the div i want to maintain its initial 100% viewport size.

Comment: I don't think it's doable with CSS, you will need JS ... *Anybody can show me how to do that?* --> start searching how to read some value using JS then search how to use those values

Comment: Thanks, I'll be looking into it. Just wanted to make sure it is indeed javascript and not doable with css.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need a javascript for that. The  height: 100vh; from your code will do just fine.